# URL not found when trying to run on port 5000''

Tags: flask

```
app = Flask(__name__)
#rest of code here...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000
```

When trying to access localhost:5000, I get an error saying:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

04/Feb/2021 02:42:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: We can't reproduce this problem with the current code. Could you post a more complete version? We call that a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you defined a `/` route in your code? Like this: `@app.route('/') def home(): ...`

Comment: that was it, had a accidental question mark after the /. Thanks for the help costaparas